# Entire JSON into One SQLite Field with Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite, pyquery

I have what is likely an easy question.  I'm trying to pull a JSON from an online source, and store it in a SQLite table.  In addition to storing the data in a rich table, corresponding to the many fields in the JSON, I would like to also just dump the entire JSON into a table every time it is pulled.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Raw_JSONs (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, T DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')), JSON text);
```

I've pulled a JSON from some URL using the following python code:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
from lxml import etree
import urllib

x = PyQuery(url='json')
y = x('p').text()
```

Now, I'd like to execute the following INSERT command:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('a.db')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("insert into Raw_JSONs values(NULL,DATETIME('now'),?)", y)
```

But I'm told that I've supplied the incorrect number bindings (i.e. thousands, instead of just 1).  I gather it's reading the y variable as all the different elements of the JSON.

Can someone help me store just the JSON, in it's entirety?

Also, as I'm obviously new to this JSON game, any online resources to recommend would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: You might like to look at document-oriented dbs, which basically store JSON natively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.execute()` expects a *sequence*, better give it a one-element tuple:

```
c.execute("insert into Raw_JSONs values(NULL,DATETIME('now'),?)", (y,))
```

A Python string is a sequence too, one of individual characters. So the `.execute()` call tried to treat each separate character as a parameter for your query, and unless your string is one character short that means it'll not provide the right number of parameters.

Don't forget to commit your inserts:

```
db.commit()
```

or use the database connection as a context manager:

```
with db:
    # inserts executed here will automatically commit if no exceptions are raised.
```

Comment: And it was that easy.  Thanks kindly.

Comment: New problem; apologies.  Please let me know if you think this should be a separate thread.

Comment: Do you commit after insertion? `connection.commit()` or use the connection as a context manager.

Comment: @user1893148: Normally, this should be a new question, really.

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested to know about the built in sqlite modules adapters.  These can convert any python object to an sqlite column both ways.  See the standard [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and the adapters section.