# Json data into one sqlite field with Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm pulling data from a website using their api. I'm then wanting to save the data into a database. For some of the fields I need to save a section of the json data that was pulled into one field.

The table layout is created using this:

```
cur.execute('create table if not exists KillData(KillID INT, Victim TEXT, KillTime TEXT, System INT,'
            ' Attackers TEXT, Items TEXT, Price REAL)')
```

This is what I have right now to insert the data:

```
for kill_mail in response:
    kill = KillMail(kill_mail)
    cur.execute("insert into KillData values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                (int(kill.get_kill_id()), kill.get_victim(), kill.get_kill_time(), kill.get_system(),
                 kill.get_attackers, kill.get_items(), kill.get_price()))
```

where KillMail is just a class which is used to get certain values within the json data.
For example:

```
class KillMail:
def __init__(self, json_kill_mail):
    self.json_kill_mail = json_kill_mail

def get_attackers(self):
    return json.dumps(self.json_kill_mail['attackers'])

def get_items(self):
    return json.dumps(self.json_kill_mail['items'])
```

kill.get_attackers and kill.get_items() contain items within them because there may be only one attacker/item or up to 100 or more. This is why I'm thinking that saving the data in json format as a string will be best so that when pulling it I can just json.load() to reconstruct the json object to pull info from it.

The error I'm getting when running the code is:

> in main
>       kill.get_attackers, kill.get_items(), kill.get_price()))
>   sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.

The only thing I could find online about doing this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505380/entire-json-into-one-sqlite-field-with-python).

I tried the suggested things in that post but nothing seemed to work.
I also tried to change the two fields to BLOB's but that gave the same error.

So my question is: How can I save a json formatted string into one field?

I can post more info if needed.

Comment: Um. For starters, to save a json-formatted string you need to *pass it a json-formatted string*. `str()` doesn't json-format things, `json.dumps` does. This alone isn't your problem, but check the type of "parameter 1" in your query, which looks to be `kill.get_victim()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I updated the post to correct those errors. The error now returns parameter 4 instead of 1 because I used your suggestion which fixed the issue with parameter 1.

Comment: parameter 4 is `kill.get_attackers`, which is a function, not the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems it was a typo on my part. For the table setup there was a set of '' that was not supposed to be in there. The table setup looked like this if you put it all on one line and not two lines like I had it:

```
cur.execute('create table if not exists KillData(KillID INT, Victim TEXT, Attackers TEXT, Items Text,'' KillTime TEXT, System INT, Price REAL)')
```

So, by removing the '' before KillTime the error no longer happens and the code works.